# Import data from CSV file into MySql produces incorrect value

Tags: mysql, excel, import

I want to import data from a CSV file to MySQL database. I find this code from another website

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE ‘C:\\temp\\yourfile.csv’
INTO TABLE database.table
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' (Date, a, b);
```

After I run this code, Column `Date` and `a` output correct data, but the value for column 'b' is 0. I am not sure what is wrong with this. Any help is appreciated.

My CSV file is something like this (it is created in Excel 2013)

```
Date         a      b
4/11/2013   111     77
4/12/2013   113     70
4/13/2013   112     72
4/14/2013   111     73
4/15/2013   110     71
4/16/2013   117     70
4/17/2013   118     76
4/18/2013   111     72
4/19/2013   115     73
4/20/2013   124     82
4/21/2013   111     70
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this SQL statment:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE ‘C:\\temp\\yourfile.csv’
INTO TABLE database.table
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' (Date, a, b);
```

You entered into your SQL statment as fild terminater a comma, but your csv file seems be use tabs.

Comment: thanks, but it doesn't work. i tried this code and now my 'a' and 'b' have null values.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solves. I actually have an empty column in my csv file. An empty column between 'a' and 'b'.